# How can detect an application is uninstallable?

Tags: android, uninstallation

I'm going to uninstall an application when user click on a button. with this code:

```
Uri packageURI = Uri.parse("package:"
        + pkNames[position]);
Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(
Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageURI);
context.startActivity(uninstallIntent);
```

but some application don't uninstallable. like Setting or Music or ... when i am going to uninstall these applications i see : uninstall not successful.

I get my packages with this code :

```
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        packages = pm.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
```

How can i detect an application is uninstallable or not?

Comment: see this sample : http://source-android.frandroid.com/development/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/content/InstallApk.java

Comment: I see this post. it's use startActivityForResult but i want to detect it and disable button. in this solution we must go to uninstall and then we can know that it's can't uninstall

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check if the application you are trying to uninstall is "system" by looking into `ApplicationInfo.flags`. System application have `ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM` bit set.
Here is a little piece of code:

```
boolean isSystem(ApplicationInfo info) {
   return (info.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0;
}
```

Check [documentation for ApplicationInfo class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html) for other useful flags.

Comment: This is incorrect. some system apps can be uninstalled. For example, the Play store is a system app and it can be uninstalled to go to the menufacturer's version of it. You need to also check the FLAG_UPDATED_SYSTEM_APP flag.